# How to batch rename multiple files which have two periods on Windows 10

Tags: windows, rename, filenames

We have 1000+ files in a folder which was created by SSMS such as

```
"aaa.storedporcedure.sql"
"bbbb.storedporcedure.sql"
"ccccc.storedporcedure.sql"
...

We want to remove the .storedporcedure from the file name to have the below file name'
"aaa,sql"
"bbbb.sql"
"ccccc.sql"
...
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `"aaa,sql"`is a typo, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

UNtested. Run it from console in directory where your files reside. If you want to use it in batch file, double all percent signs.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %a in ('dir /B') do ren %a.%b.sql %a.sql
```